# issue in datatables to show the complete message in csv file

Tags: jquery, csv, datatables

I have a list of records and I am showing those by using datatables plugin. Among those columns, I have a column in which I am showing record by using wordwrap(20 characters) and if user mouses over the record then by using tooltip he can see the full text.
Now when user clicks on "save to csv" button, then only truncated messages it is storing in csv file. So is there any option to show the full text in csv?

My code is like:

```
oTable = $('#data-table').dataTable( {
       "sDom": 'CT<"clear">firtlip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": basePath+"/js/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
            "aButtons": [ {"sExtends": "csv","sFileName" : curpath+".csv","sButtonText": "Save to CSV","mColumns": "visible"} ]
        },
       "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
       "bAutoWidth":false,
       "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
       "iDisplayLength": 10,
       "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "Filter : "
                  },
       'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
    } );
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can specificly alter the data which is added to the csv-export, but maybe you can do it a bit different.

Instead of truncating the data yourself and showing the full data only in the tooltip, you could add the full text and use css to do the shortening for you with these styles on the containing element:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

The csv-export then should contain all the data.